# Is there a way to make a ball bounce endlesly? (using soft body and physics)

Tags: physics, soft-body

I can make a ball bounce endlessly by using keyframes - but i'm looking for that cool softbody+phsyics "giggle" when the ball gets when it hits the ground. Unfortunately i couldn't figure out if its possible to use physics and make the ball bounce endlessly (I mean from Z 100cm to 0cm and back to 100 and 0 again and again)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Basically prepare your physics simulation as you like, bake the frames, and apply cycles modifier in the graph editor

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have the animation I want, but there is no way to bake softbody to keyframes?
I just want the shapekeys of the "Squish" part of the bounce and then bounce it manually using keyframes..

I tried using the .mdd exporter\importer but i cant seem to control that animation properly.

Comment: there is a way exporting as .mdd, but honestly, I am not familiar with that method, I tried it myself and I get a messy animation, but have read a bunch of comments and everyone saying this works like a charm. perhaps you would like to give it a try. Make sure the "NewTek MDD format" add-on is enabled in the user preferences, and then select the object and go File > Export > Lightwave Pointcache (.mdd).

Comment: hello, I just want you to know that I was playing with the technique I told you about exporting as .MMD and it worked like a charm... so that is the right path or one of the hundreds of paths to achieve this.

Comment: Here is the link to download the project files. [DOWNLOAD PROJECT FILES](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lab6hvs54k3xjrf/Infinit%20Bouncing.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

You should play with the SURFACE RESPONSE > BOUNCINESS parameter of the ball and the plane (you can also set there parameters to let the ball increase the height at every bounce).